# c# draw chart in existing form

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I'm actually learning C# and especially Windows forms with Visual Studio.
My `main()` runs good and it calls the different function, but I have a problem when I call the following function `CreationDessin()`.
The function is called but there is no charts add to my form (the form is displayed but empty).
Does anybody have an idea of the problem? 
Is the `Cart.Invalidate()` inappropriate in this case?

Thanks for your help,

Here is a part of my main script :

```
Form1 myform2 = new Form1();
myform2.CreationDessin(myform2, i, ListBarreX, ListBarreY, ListLabelX, 
ListLabelY, ListLabelValue);
myform2.ShowDialog();
```

Here is my CreationDessin script :

```
namespace AddPanel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public void CreationDessin(object sender, int ChartNumber, List<int> XValues, List<int> YValues, List<int> LabelXValues, List<int> LabelYValues, List<int> Label)
        {

            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart Chart = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
            Chart.Name = "Faconnage" + (ChartNumber + 1).ToString();
            Chart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1014, 47 + 300 * ChartNumber);
            Chart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(357, 204);
            Chart.TabIndex = 2;


            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea ChartArea = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
            ChartArea.Name = "ChartArea1";
            Chart.ChartAreas.Add(ChartArea);           

            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series Series = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
            Series.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
            Chart.Series.Add(Series);
            Series.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
            Series.IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
            Series.Name = "Series1";
            Series.Points.DataBindXY(XValues, YValues);


            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series SeriesLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
            SeriesLabel.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
            Chart.Series.Add(Series);
            SeriesLabel.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
            SeriesLabel.IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
            SeriesLabel.Name = "Series" + (i + 2).ToString();
            SeriesLabel.Points.DataBindXY(XValues, YValues);

            Chart.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Controls to be displayed on the surface of a control container like a form need to be added to the container Controls collection. _(sender as Form).Controls.Add(Chart);_

Answer (score 0):

Your first argument shouldn't be of type object since you already know it's type. Now assuming you would want to add your chart in, for example: A Form, Panel, GroupBox, etc... Here's a general solution:

```
public void CreationDessin(Control ctrl, int ChartNumber, List<int> XValues, List<int> YValues, List<int> LabelXValues, List<int> LabelYValues, List<int> Label)
{
    // Set chart options etc
    ctrl.Controls.Add(Chart); // IMPORTANT
}
```

And you can simply use this like:

```
myform2.CreationDessin(myform2, i, ListBarreX, ListBarreY, ListLabelX, ListLabelY, ListLabelValue);

// Or even

myform2.CreationDessin(myPanel1, i, ListBarreX, ListBarreY, ListLabelX, ListLabelY, ListLabelValue);
```